# Setting up an Angular/Ionic Mobile Application with MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, ionic-framework

I was wondering if anyone could help me at all.

I posted a previous question in regards to this title but I didn't receive much of a response (probably due to lack of information).

I started out with an Ionic Application and built the view files using state URLS to navigate from page to page in the WWW folder. I've then created corresponding controllers for the view files, for basic calls and functionality that I want my app to do in the front-end via Ionic.

My question is how do I setup MongoDB + Mongoose so I can have access to the models I have created?

I have scoured the internet but to no avail, I mean I know there is no set way to define a model within this type of application but some general guidance would be really appreciated.

I understand that when building an application with Angular you're essentially building 2 applications, the front-end where your CSS, JS and HTML goes with the front-end frameworks on top of them.

Then the backend application that runs the server, stores data and runs the business logic. This is where I have created the User Schema model for my application and have inserted a document into my database via the MongoDB shell whilst running mongod.

However I also created a users.js in another models folder in my front-end where I'm returning a resource following a url with either a get, save, query, remove or delete.

First of all I would like to say I'm relatively new to building mobile applications so this may even be entirely wrong and secondly up to this point I get lost as to what to do in my application.

I have tried setting up an express server in my app.js file and I can connect to it via my terminal as it is listening on the port number, but in the browser it is coming up with cannot /GET.

If you need any more information please feel free to ask, I know I haven't really gone into any technicals, but I'm really not sure even if I'm asking the right questions to begin with.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4). You can set up a RESTful Api using Express.js and you can make calls to that API from any client. Your mobile app will be one of the clients. You should reframe your question and try to create a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It looks like you need to post code from your `app.js` file and ask why you are getting `cannot/GET`

Comment: Hello Inspired, thank you for your response I will definitely checkout the tutorial I'm giving it a read over now, so hopefully I would find some usefull information in there. I will also rename my question when I get a chance. once again thanks for the link and I will get back to you with some feedback. cheers.